# What is a good separation between UI and logic?

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am trying to create some n-tier application and I am having difficulties separating the UI and the logic and I am wondering what belongs to the UI and what belongs to the logic.

For example a simple application which allows you to login and then asks the user to fill in a form or display a list of previous forms. I can think of two possible solutions:

1. The logic tells the UI it needs to login, the UI then asks the user for the username and password and sends it to the logic. The logic then tells the UI it needs to ask the user if they want to fill in a form or display the previous forms. The UI then sends this choice to the logic and the logic tells the UI to display a form or to display the list.
   Here the UI has no state and is really dumb, basically the logic has to tell the UI what to show and when to show it.
2. The UI shows a login form and when the user enters the username/password, the UI sends those to the logic to login. If the login was successfull, the UI asks the user what to do, if the user wants to show the form it displays the form, if it wants to display the list, the UI asks the logic for a list of items to display.
   Here the UI has state and makes decisions about what to show next on its own. The logic is only used for providing information to the UI and for processing information send by the UI. The logic has no state and just does what the UI tells it to do.

I like 1 because the UI is stateless and if the UI crashes (but not the logic which runs in a different process) you can restart the UI and continue in the same place before it crashed. It makes the UI very light weight and simple. But I am wondering which is better:
put the state about what the user is doing in the UI or in the logic.

edit:

I found a [document](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DudeWheresMyBusinessLogic.aspx) describing where to put logic but it is mainly on  logic and data, not the UI. Is there a similar document describing the logic and UI part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm following an MVP type of architecture for the current projects I'm working on and I think it's great.  My views have no knowledge of the model and communicate with the presenter via an interface.  From inside my presenter I talk to a service layer that in turn talks to my model.  My View and my model are completely ignorant of each other.  The View will forward events into my presenter and expose properties that the presenter can update based on logic inside the presenter.

Comment: sounds good, but how do you decide what goes in the presenter and what goes into the view?

Comment: The only code in my views (besides the actual UI layout) are properties mapped to controls or events that forward control to handlers in the presenter.  The views are extremely thin and my presenter handles all of the responses to user events as well as updating the view.

Comment: Are things like menus (for example) hardcoded in the view or does the presenter provides a list of menu items to the view?

Comment: No, I have the presenter actually build the markup for the menus and return it to the view.  The view will usually have a div or some sort of container that the markup is injected into.

Comment: I think this (in combination with a REST architecture) describes my final solution best.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably MVC (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC), that being said, the composition and the display of an UI (view) should be separated from the business rules and ultimately, these should be separated from the data itself.

Comment: no, I want n-tier, I do not want my UI to mess with my data directly.

Comment: @Hunter2: In MVC there is a direct connection between model and view, I do not want that. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-tier#Comparison_with_the_MVC_architecture

Comment: @rve: what meant under the wikipedia's link is that your UI must alway use some controller to get it's data for display and must never use direct access to data layer, such as database. However, there's always *direct* link between model and view, even in n-tier -- your view gets data ("model") to display from logic ("controller").